# Partitioning Employees Into Job Familes With Below / Above Rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some Excel data that looks like this:

```
Name | Job Family | Salary
```

I also have a list of rules that look like this:

```
Job Family | Grade | Minimum Salary | Maximum Salary       
Accounting | 12    | 108000         | 160000   
Accounting | 11    | 79000          | 107999
```

How can I retrieve a grade for each employee?

Thanks

Comment: Multiple job families will use the same grades. Within each job family, each grade is used only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar solution screenshot]

In cell D2 and copied down is this formula (as shown in the image):

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,B2,H:H,"<="&C2,I:I,">="&C2)
```

Comment: Perfect! Hadn't considered SUMIFs.